# Presto | Athena: Duplicated values in not key column

Tags: sql, distinct, presto, trino

I have the following table:

| CD_CLIENTE | DE_CLIENTE |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | Jhon One |
| 23456 | Jhon Two |
| 34567 | Jhon Three |
| 12345 | Jhon ONEe |

Even using `DISTINCT` for CD_CLIENT I have it two times in my Result because the CD_CLIENT is equal, but DE_CLIENTE is different

My question:

```
select distinct taxid as CD_CLIENTE, name as DE_CLIENTE
FROM my_table_name
group by distinct taxid, name
```

I need this query to achive this result, without the duplicated CD_CLIENTE:

| CD_CLIENTE | DE_CLIENTE |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | Jhon One |
| 23456 | Jhon Two |
| 34567 | Jhon Three |

I tryed this:

```
select distinct taxid as CD_CLIENTE, name as DE_CLIENTE
FROM my_table_name
group by distinct taxid, name
```

| CD_CLIENTE | DE_CLIENTE |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | Jhon One |
| 23456 | Jhon Two |
| 34567 | Jhon Three |
| 12345 | Jhon ONEe |

And need this:

| CD_CLIENTE | DE_CLIENTE |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | Jhon One |
| 23456 | Jhon Two |
| 34567 | Jhon Three |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping both by `taxid, name` so you will get all unique combinations of `taxid` and `name` in the output. `DISTINCT` is irrelevant here since it uses all columns in the select to perform comparisons for uniqueness (i.e. you can remove either `group by` or `distinct` the result will be the same).

One option is to remove `name` from the `group by` clause and use aggregate like `arbitrary` or `max`:

```
-- sample data
WITH dataset(taxid, name) AS (
    VALUES (12345,  'Jhon One'),
        (23456, 'Jhon Two'),
        (34567, 'Jhon Three'),
        (12345, 'Jhon ONEe')
)

-- query
select taxid, max(name)
from dataset
group by taxid;
```

Output:

| taxid | _col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | Jhon One |
| 34567 | Jhon Three |
| 23456 | Jhon Two |

if you have some third column you can use to resolve "collisions" for name you can use `max_by`/`min_by` (`max_by(name, some_3rd_col)`).